# Кастомизация save и create в Backbone

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

Добрый день,

в ходе разработке приложения столкнулся с одной забавной штукой:

При редактировании данных (читай, редактирование конкретной модели) и последующем сохранении (save) нужно отменить отправку всей модели и послать лишь определенный набор в JSON.

Итак, допустим наша модель выглядит так:

```
{
att1: "value1",
att2: "value2",
att3: "value3",
att4: "value4",
att5: "value5",
att6: "value6",
att7: "value7",
}
```

Карточка редактирования позволяет изменить, например, только первые 3 атрибута. Но по дефолту backbone посылает всю модель, а этот формат не принимает сервер.

Можно воспользоваться опцией **patch:true**, и послать только изменившиеся атрибуты, но что будет, если пользователь открыл карточку, ничего не отредактировал, но нажал кнопку сохранить? В моей версии Backbone (1.2.1) поведение такое, что если ничего не поменялось, то даже при patch:true посылается вся модель, что не принимается сервером.

Решил изменить дефолтное поведение sync. Добавил в возможные опции передачи ключ **passed: {objHere}**, сам sync расширил так:

```
sync: function(method, model, options) {
...
  if(options.passed) {
    options.data = JSON.stringify(options.passed);
  }
...
  return Backbone.sync.apply(this, arguments);
},
```

Что я имею? данные отправляются и сохраняются, как надо, даже если ничего не изменилось, сервер возвращает статус 200, однако функция save выплёвывает error и срабатывает не тот колбэк, в то время, как все отлично работает.

Вопрос: где выпрямлять руки?

Использовать в тупую аяксовский запрос, в обход стандартных средств сохранения Backbone нельзя, потому что у модели есть валидатор, принимающий отправляемые данные, проверяющий их и, если что то не так, то отменяющий отправку.

Comment: Backbone-модель нужна для синхронизации данных с сервером (читай, чтение/создание/обновление/удаление). Какой смысл создавать модель, формат которой не подходит для сервера? Чем вас не устраивает модель сервера?

Comment: меня всё устраивает, я бы обновлял её, как должно, если бы не одно замечательно но: api для апдейта данных не принимает все те же самые данные, что отдаёт. Т.е. если я передаю лишние атрибуты, то получаю ошибку. Поэтому приходятся формировать JSON с нужными атрибутами, которые собираются из input'ов и отправлять save'ом. И получаю я их в одном формате, а отправлять должен в чуть чуть другом (если дополнительный обязательный вложенный JSON, без которого сервер тоже вернет ошибку)

Comment: ну и изменение стандартного поведения некоторых частей фреймворка - это нормально, это практикуется довольно часто. Общая часть остаётся неизменной, но что-нибудь добавляется, ключ например, - если он есть, выполняется другая логика - нет, значит всё по дефолту и остальная часть приложения работает стабильно

Comment: А подойдет ли вариант с `patch: true` - не отправлять запрос вообще , если ничего не изменилось?

Comment: да, подойдёт, осталось понять, как это заэкстендить =)

Comment: Еще можно переопределить метод toJSON в котором сделать логику и проверку того, что отправлять на сервер.

Comment: не совсем понял, что имеется в виду с toJSON

Comment: backbone очень хорошо расширяется. переопределите метод save вашей модели. загуглите backbone model overwrite method и увидите как это делается

Comment: да, конкретно save я не пробовал переопределить, но если судить по исходникам самого Backbone, он всё равно передаёт управление sync, сам save просто до этой передачи вызывает еще set. Однако предложенный вами способ (его же предложил arnage ниже), я опробую. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно в опциях передать поле data, которое перетрет данные, отправляемые на сервер моделью по-умолчанию

```
model.save({}, {
    type: 'post',
    data: {
       attr1: model.get('attr1'),
       attr2: model.get('attr2'),
       attr3: model.get('attr3')
    },
    processData: true,
    success: function(){...},
    error: function(){...}
})
```

Comment: вот это я не пробовал, но я пробовал создать новый ключ, который бы передавал нужные мне данные. Далее, был расширен стандартный sync и, если эта опция передаётся, то заменять data на то, что я передаю. Это работало, данные на сервер сохранялись, но save тригеррил error, а не success, хотя сервер после приёма отдавал статус 200 (т.е. ок). Это описано в первом посте. Но я попробую ваш метод, спасибо!